# For loop is not iterating within setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why this for loop does not render out 0,1,2,3 like its suppose to.

It renders `4, 4 , 4, 4`.

How would i get this to print `0, 1, 2, 3` with the setTimeout still in place ?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
    setTimeout(function() {     
        console.log('The index of this number is: ' + i);   
    }, 3000); 
}
```

Comment: it appears that by changing var to let it works, idk why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Create another and call it on each iteration

```js
function a(i)
{
 setTimeout(function() {     
        console.log('The index of this number is: ' + i);   
    }, 3000); 
}

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
   a(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you have a reason why the code that i posted does't print your solution  ?